# Setting docker with nginx and php5

Tags: php, nginx, docker, dockerfile

Trying to setup docker with nginx and php5. Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.9.9

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install php5-fpm php5-mysql php-apc php5-imagick\
        php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-gd php5-pgsql\
        php5-common php-pear curl php5-json

ADD index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
ADD index.php /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
ADD default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

RUN /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

I am able to build this just fine with the following command:

```
sudo docker build -t myuser/nginx-php5:0.1 .
```

And then I launch it as follows:

```
sudo docker run -d -P myuser/nginx-php5:0.1
```

The nginx deamon is running, I can indeed see my index.html, yet, index.php gets 'downloaded' rather than served. This indicates that PHP is not properly set...

My default file:

```
server {
listen  80;

root /var/www;
index index.php index.html;

server_name localhost;

access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.com-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.com-error.log error;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I guess the problem is that I am not doing the proper things to keep php5-fpm running.. but how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think php-fpm didn't run, so nginx just returns php file instead of passing to php-fpm to process.
You should create an "entrypoint.sh" file to launch nginx and php-fpm when run the container. Besides you must correctly set user and group for php-fpm worker processes.

Comment: Yeah, the issue seems to be that php5-fpm is not running.. Reading further, it appears that docker containers are supposed to only run one process, and that I should use [Supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/) to handle multiple ones..